# How can we intregrate Apache Solr with Play Java Framework

Tags: java, solr, playframework-2.0

I want to integrate Apache Solr search with this Play Framework. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Solr from Scala/ Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547581/using-solr-from-scala-play)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Solr asynchronous from Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270393/call-solr-asynchronous-from-play-framework)

Comment: There are several Scala clients for Solr if that is what you want to do. If you are using Play in Java, why not just use SolrJ?